# Static image vehicle recognition using opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a project of using a camera to take a picture for detecting the available parking space in the carpark.

I am going to use image subtraction for comparing the empty and occupied situation in the carpark.

These are the two picture for comparison

[image]

This is the resulting image:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to

1. recognize and put a rectangle outside the vehicle
2. output the number of the car for my further usage?

Here is the code:

```
    // Test.cpp

#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat bg_frame;
Mat cam_frame;
Mat diff_frame;
char charCheckForEscKey = 0;

int main() {

    while (charCheckForEscKey != 27 /*&& capWebcam.isOpened()*/) {

    bg_frame = imread("Picture1.jpg",0);
    cam_frame = imread("Picture4.jpg",0);

    resize(cam_frame, cam_frame, bg_frame.size());

    imshow("test1", bg_frame);
    imshow("test2", cam_frame);

    absdiff(bg_frame, cam_frame, diff_frame);

    threshold(diff_frame, diff_frame, 80, 255, THRESH_BINARY);


    //erode(diff_frame, diff_frame, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(1, 1)));

    dilate(diff_frame, diff_frame, Mat(), Point(-1, -1));

    //Canny(diff_frame, diff_frame, 30, 70);

    imshow("test3", diff_frame);

    charCheckForEscKey = cv::waitKey(1);            // delay (in ms) and get key press, if any
    }

    return(0);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very complex to be solved in a single post, but I will give you some pointers on how to solve it.

The idea is correct, you should compare the differences between images. I would not recommend comparing directly pixel by pixel, but its a fast solution for a prototype. For more robust methods checkout [background subtraction c++](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html) and [more extense but in python](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html)

As for counting the number of vehicles, given the complexity of the scene (overlapping cars, non uniform parking) then I would recommend manually specifying a region of interest (ROI) for each car. Applying the method you already have for each ROI, you can detect if that parking space is occupied or not.

On how to [draw a rectangle](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle) in opencv.

```
void rectangle(Mat& img, Point pt1, Point pt2, const Scalar& color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, int shift=0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, can you talk about more about ROI?

Comment: its simply a rectangular section of the image, a series of pixels that define a region. In your case its a region per parking space. This way you can split the global problem to a simple case of "is this image a car or an empty park space?"